# How can i render an image from my database in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have the following jsx component:

Game

```
import React from 'react'
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import '../../styles/components/Games/Game.css'


function Game({game}) {

  const { name, description, employees, hours, photo } = game;

  const formatDateTime = (dateTimeString) => {
  const dateTime = new Date(dateTimeString);
  const day = dateTime.getDate();
  const month = dateTime.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = dateTime.getFullYear();
  const hours = String(dateTime.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
  const minutes = String(dateTime.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');

  return `${day}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`;
  };

  const openingTimes = hours.map((time) => formatDateTime(time.opening));
  const closingTimes = hours.map((time) => formatDateTime(time.closing));

  return (
    <div className='game_card'>
        <div className="game_heading">
            <div className="image_container">
                <img src={`http://localhost:5000/public/uploads/${photo}`} alt="no photo" />
            </div>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="game_content">
            <p>Game Description</p>
            <div className="game_hours">
            {`${openingTimes} ${closingTimes}`}
            </div>
        </div>
        <button><ExpandMoreIcon/></button>
        <div className="employees">
            <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Game
```

And in my API which is running in port 5000 i store in public/uploads all my images. But for some reason i am not being able to render them.

Here is an example of a game object in my reactjs app.

```
{
    "_id": "648a5a8beccdb1f0cc27e026",
    "name": "Fantasy World",
    "description": "Immerse yourself in a realm of imagination and wonder with captivating rides and shows.",
    "photo": "photo_648a5a8beccdb1f0cc27e026.jpg",
    "employees": [
        "5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5d8",
        "5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5d9"
    ],
    "hours": [
        {
            "opening": "2023-06-07T12:00:00.000Z",
            "closing": "2023-06-07T22:00:00.000Z",
            "_id": "648a5a8beccdb1f0cc27e027"
        },
        {
            "opening": "2023-06-08T14:00:00.000Z",
            "closing": "2023-06-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_id": "648a5a8beccdb1f0cc27e028"
        }
    ],
    "available": true,
    "createdAt": "2023-06-07T16:00:00.000Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And in my api i have for example `public/uploads/photo_648a5a8beccdb1f0cc27e026.jpg`

If in the `alt` property of an `img` component i put `{photo}` the name of the file is properly displayed. But i am not being able to render the image itself.

Comment: @LinDu for some reason `<img src={`http://localhost:5000/uploads/${photo}`} alt="no photo" />` is working but i am storing the pictures in public/uploads, shouldnt the src be `<img src={`http://localhost:5000/public/uploads/${photo}`} alt="no photo" />` ???

Comment: Please edit your question with debugging details, don't put them in comment

Comment: This is entirely dependant on how static content is served from your API. If I guessed, you have `app.use(express.static("public"))` which would mean URLs should **not** include the `public` prefix

Comment: Please mention your nodejs code also or screenshots of it.